# Firebase FireStore disableNetwork offline usage cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I perform some query offline actions (no updates, just reading data), such as in the code below, will that count against my quota?

Will I be charged for those operations?

```
Firebase.firestore().disableNetwork()
        .then(function() {
            // Do offline reading queries
            // ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are only billed for documents that get read on the cloud service side.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, I am considering firebase, but my app is database intensive, and I am concerned about cutting the costs. I already have a local db for caching static data. Is there a good strategy to keep the price down, maybe using offline reading queries instead?

Comment: That question is a too broad for Stack Overflow.  If you want to solicit general ideas for how to architect your app, you should post to a discussion group, such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/